# Get raw request headers in django

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, nginx

Is there any way to get the full unprocessed HTTP request headers in django (hosted on elastic beanstalk?)

I would like to be able to analyze the ordering of the headers in particular, so unfortunately `HttpRequest.META` does not suffice for my use case.

Comment: This could help -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/middleware/#process-request

Comment: Thanks @Gocht, but unfortunately by the time `process_request` gets the `HttpRequest`, `HttpRequest.META` has already been converted to a dict and has lost it's ordering information.

Comment: why is ordering important?

Comment: It's interesting for research purposes as a means for identifying bot traffic where headers were constructed from a dict

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - you cannot do this at the Django level. The contents of `HttpRequest.META` are [obtained directly from the WSGI handler](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2fcafd169b5fcf4bb6711ca8aa4d59d80225ec7a/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py#L96). The structure of this object is defined in the [WSGI specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#environ-variables).

The request headers are a `dict` even before Django gets anywhere near them - your WSGI handler (uwsgi/gunicorn/weurkzeug in development) is what parses the headers and passes the `dict` to your Django application. Django has no knowledge of the original, raw, request headers.

The only place to get the raw request would be at web server (Nginx/Apache etc) level. I know you can log these with Nginx - although you would be logging a substantial amount of data.

Comment: That's the impression I got after poking around the source for a while but I was hoping that Django might have some way of doing it anyway.